# Counting trees with condition

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Hey guys I'm try to count the number of trees with number of vertices = n,

**such that all vertices except for two have degree 2.**

I would like to get some hint for that question , thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since the total number of edges in a trees with $n$ vertices is $n\!-\!1$, and the sum of vertex degrees is twice the number of edges, we can see that the two vertices with degree $\ne 2$ both have degree $1$. There is therefore only **one** such tree for each value of $n$ - a [path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_graph).